# Selenium webdriver get into element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to download this PDF with Python selenium

http://www.ortmtlb.org.lb/images/stories/raiati/2021/raiati%201_2021.pdf

How to get the download element with CSS selector?

Answer (score 0):

You might find this doc useful and here is an example:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
```

You have to select the element by id or tag name

For details you can see [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/locating-elements-by-tagname-in-selenium#:%7E:text=Well%2C%20in%20a%20scenario%20where,tr%20%3E%20tag%20to%20retrieve%20data).

Answer (score 0):

Why you need selenium use

```
import urllib.request 


urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.ortmtlb.org.lb/images/stories/raiati/2021/raiati%201_2021.pdf', "a.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Should automatically download any pdf files that open.

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',  {
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
    }
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
driver.get('http://www.ortmtlb.org.lb/images/stories/raiati/2021/raiati%201_2021.pdf')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```